# netbeans 8.0.2 html preview

Tags: html, netbeans, ide

I just installed netbeans 8.0.2 for an html/css/js project, and realized it doesn't have an included html preview function that allows me to see what my webpage looks like as I develop it.  To view the page I need to save the file and open it in a dedicated browser.  I found a plugin for an older version of netbeans (7.0.4) that allows this functionality, but I don't believe it will work for this newer version.  Any solutions?   Should I just abandon netbeans and use a different IDE?